# Serializable attribute exists in both System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters and nunit.framework

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, nuget-package, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I have issue with Serializable attribute:

> The type 'SerializableAttribute' exists in both
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' and
>   'nunit.framework, Version=3.4.1.0.

```
`{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "testRunner": "nunit",
  "buildOptions": {
    "debugType": "portable",
    "allowUnsafe": true,
    "define": [ "WIN64" ]
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "buildOptions": {
        "compile": {
          "exclude": [ "Tests/**/*.cs", "Examples/**/**/AssemblyInfo.cs" ]
        },
        "define": [ "NETSTANDARD1_6" ]
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
        "System.Runtime": "4.1.0",
        "System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters": "4.0.0-rc3-24212-01",
        "System.Dynamic.Runtime": "4.0.11",
        "System.Threading.ThreadPool": "4.0.10",
        "System.Reflection.TypeExtensions": "4.1.0",
        "System.Diagnostics.StackTrace": "4.0.1",
        "System.Diagnostics.Process": "4.1.0",
        "System.Threading.Thread": "4.0.0",
        "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-beta-1",
        "NUnit": "3.4.1"
      },
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    },
    "net451": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NUnit": "3.4.1",
        "dotnet-test-nunit": "3.4.0-alpha-2"
      },
      "buildOptions": {
        "compile": {
          "exclude": [ "Tests/**/*.cs", "Tests/service-bus-tests-net4/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs", "Examples/service-example-csharp-dispatcher/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs", "Examples/service-example-csharp/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs" ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "ubuntu.14.04-x64": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win7-x64": {}
  }
}`
```